# Call C# Method from C# Dll using Reflection

Tags: c#, dll, reflection

Good day,
I've got following problem. I'm working on my .dll library in C#, and I need to call a method of another C# project from the dll library. 
For example I create a WPF project and I add reference of my .dll library.

Here is my WPF class (project):

```
using dllLibrary;

namespace Tester
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my .dll project :

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Tester.MainWindow");
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("MyMethod");
return method.Invoke(instance, null);
```

By the way, it works when I call a method inside of the assembly 
(of the dll project), but when I want to call a method outside of the dll project (Tester.MainWindow - the WPF project), it doesn't work.

Comment: define "it doesn't work".

Comment: Is in your dll project wpf class loaded dynamically?

Comment: Yes, they are ok. I can see others method of DLL library. But I can't call any methods of WPF project  from the DLL.

Comment: Why are you calling that method by reflection? You already have the assembly referenced, just *call the method*. No need to use reflection.

Comment: Always keep in mind that a .NET type is distinctive not only by the namespace name and type name but also by the assembly that it lives in.  And that you can think this through by yourself, you are asking the CLR to figure out which DLL to load from *just* the type name.  It doesn't know how to do that.

Comment: You could call the `GetType()` of the loaded assembly. `loadedAssembly.GetType("Tester.MainWindow");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type.GetType without the full qualified name incl. assembly only works for types in mscorlib.dll. For all other types you have to pass the full qualified name of the type. So when you change the GetType call to something like this it will work:

```
Type.GetType("Tester.MainWindow, TestAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b17a5c561934e089);
```

You can load the assembly first using Assembly.LoadFile to get the full qualified name.

Comment: It also works for the currently executing assembly, of course - which is why it worked for the OP when used in the executing assembly :)